# how to set check default radio button android with alert dialog?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog

any body help me...
how to set check default radio button with alert dialog when is launched..?

this my code , ex: **i want to set radio button when launched where items is "15"**

```
public void showDialog()
{
    final CharSequence[] items = {"5", "10", "15","20"};

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Set limit article");

    alertDialogBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(SettingAppDisplay.this, "You selected item No." + item + ": " + items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (items[item].equals("5")) {
                    //do what you want
                }
                else if (items[item].equals("10")) {
                    //do what you want                                  
                }
                else if (items[item].equals("15")) {
                    //do what you want
                }
                else if (items[item].equals("20")) {
                    //do what you want
                }

                dialog.dismiss();
            }   
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.show();

}
```

thanks your paticipation ..
sorry with my english :)

Answer (score 6):

Change second argument (checkedItem) in `setSingleChoiceItems` from  -1 to what ever position of radio button you wanted to be checked, here i changed it to '1' so first radio button will be checked.

```
 alertDialogBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(SettingAppDisplay.this, "You selected item No." + item + ": " + items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (items[item].equals("5")) {
                    //do what you want
                }
                else if (items[item].equals("10")) {
                    //do what you want                                  
                }
                else if (items[item].equals("15")) {
                    //do what you want
                }
                else if (items[item].equals("20")) {
                    //do what you want
                }

                dialog.dismiss();
            }   
    });
```

See [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems%28android.database.Cursor,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29)

```
setSingleChoiceItems (Cursor cursor, int checkedItem, String labelColumn, 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)
```

**Parameters**

***cursor***      the cursor to retrieve the items from.

***checkedItem***   specifies which item is checked. If -1 no items are checked.

***labelColumn***   The column name on the cursor containing the string to display in the label.

***listener***  notified when an item on the list is clicked. The dialog will not be dismissed when an item is clicked. It will only be dismissed if clicked on a button, if no buttons are supplied it's up to the user to dismiss the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following `android.app.AlertDialog.Builder.setSingleChoiceItems(CharSequence[] items, int 
 checkedItem, OnClickListener listener)`
Give the integer value of the position of items as second parameter checkedItem.

To make default value as 15th item give the following

```
alertDialogBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 14, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
```

Answer (score 0):

The deafault checked item is set by the middle argument in `setSingleChoiceItems`

```
alertDialogBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```

In your code you have that set to -1 which means no item will be selected by default. Just change the value to the one in your array that you want selected. Remember to start with 0 for the first one and count your way up to the item you want selected.